# An apartment with 'three bed-room' or 'a three bed-room'?

Tags: articles

I have a question about grammar.

The sentence is

> I am living in an apartment with **(a)** three bed-room.

Do I need to use indefinite articles before 'three bed-room' or not?

Answer (score 5):

The sentence is wrong in any case. "Bedroom" is not only a single word, but a countable noun - so it needs to be pluralised.

> I am living in an apartment with three bedrooms.

However perhaps you meant to use it as an adjective? In which case the article applies to the apartment:

> I am living in a three-bedroom apartment.